# how can i index bool property in document db

Tags: azure-cosmosdb

I've read [Azure DocumentDb Indexing Policies](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/documentdb/documentdb-indexing-policies).

There is no mention of how to index a bool property. Without any Json formatting wizardry the properties get written to doc db like `"prop name": true`

Do I need to output as a number?

For now I've added a path and avoided specifying the datatype. I have no way of knowing if it works.

```
{
  "path": "/IsDeprecated/?",
  "indexes": [
    {
      "kind": "Hash",
      "precision": -1
    }
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Booleans are indexed implicitly. You do not need any custom indexing configuration for Booleans (just strings, numbers, and spatial types)

Comment: Is there a reference you can point me to for this info? I've gone crazy trying to find something that says that.

Comment: @mark-lauter replace index [REST api docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/cosmos-db/replace-a-collection) mention this _Note that Booleans and nulls are automatically indexed_